Compiled TypeScript code requires ".js" extension in imports but Jest requires no extension
I tried copying TypeScript and Jest config from Z. My code is available on GitHub
tsconfig.json has:
"lib": [ "es5", "es6", "es7", "esnext", "dom" ],
    "target": "es2018",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",

Imports work if I specify .js extensions but not if there's no extension.
Jest config:
transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
},
testRegex: "test/.*\\.test\\.ts$",
moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", "json", "node"],

Babel config:
module.exports = { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] };

Imports work when there's no extension but do not work if there's a "js" extension.

Target needed to be set to "target": "ESNext" and then extension is no longer needed to run the code.
